# How to make leftmark/rightmark next to Page number?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

The desired header style is like: page number is sans serif even in the first page of the chapter, because

Using

```
\fancyhead[LE]{\sffamily \thepage  }
\fancyhead[RO]{\sffamily \thepage  }
```

could not change the font of the page number in the first page of each chapter.

In even page:   `Page number |  Chapter title`

> [image]

In odd page:  `Section title | Page number`

> [image]

Using `\fancyheadoffset[RE,LO]{-0.5\textwidth}` could not get this effect, so how to achieve this style?

Minimal page:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}    
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[ ]{titlesec} 
\usepackage[]{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\fancyhf{}     
\fancyhead{} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection~~~#1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\if@mainmatter \fi#1}{}}
\makeatother

% head setting
\fancyhead[LE]{ \sffamily \thepage $|$ } 
\fancyhead[RE]{  \leftmark  }
\fancyhead[LO]{  \rightmark  }
\fancyhead[RO]{ $|$ \sffamily\thepage}   %odd page
\fancyheadoffset[RE,LO]{-0.5\textwidth}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{ 0.5 pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
 \kant[1-5]
\section{This is a extremely  long ........... title}
  \kant[6-10]
\section{Short title}
  \kant[11-15]
\end{document}
```

In the MWE, you will find the font of the page number, is still `serif` in the first page  of `Introduction`.

Another style (see below) which is similar to the first one, the only difference is that the vertical line `|` up to the top edge.

Even page:
[image]

Odd page:
[image]

Is it possible to make the second style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using [`titleps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps) for this, since it allows easy access to sectional titles:

[image]
<sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{titleps,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{titleps,lipsum}
\newpagestyle{main}{%
  \sethead
    [\thepage\quad$\vert$\quad\chaptertitle]% even-left
    []% even-centre
    []% even-right
    {}% odd-left
    {}% odd-centre
    {\thesection~\sectiontitle\quad$\vert$\quad\thepage}% odd-right
}
\pagestyle{main}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Of course, you can add your own formatting, as needed. For example, replacing `$\vert$` with `\smash{\rule[-.5ex]{1pt}{5in}}` produces [a vertical rule that sticks down/up -0.5ex/5in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrzKn.png). With everything outside the page boundary being clipped, a long enough vertical rule is okay.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr), put this into your preamble:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark{} $|$ \thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage{} $|$ \leftmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Comment: I corrected the commands: `\fancyhead[LO]{ \thepage{} $|$  \leftmark}`
`\fancyhead[RE]{ \rightmark $|${} \thepage }`

Comment: @KOF That depends on what you want. Since odd pages are right, `RO` and `LE` are outer heads, which is what I supposed is correct.

Comment: Yes, I like the Chapter on the `Even` page and the Section `Odd` page

Comment: This does not really work for a book class. See this chat message: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18561046#18561046

Comment: You're missing `\pagestyle{fancy}` I would say (I didn't test though). Well, I'm missing that too, so I'll add it.